# Where do i get an HTC-Hero ROM

Tags: htc-hero, rom, updates

I have an HTC Hero Android Version:2.3.3, i want to figure out if i can downgraded it to a previous version that the Hero can actually handle.

- I don't know if my android is rooted, and not sure how to find out
- I don't know if my phone is upgradable/downgradeable or not  and
- and I  have no idea Where I can get a nice clean ROM for my phone

Comment: How did you get Android 2.3 on there if you don't know if its rooted?  Chances are pretty good (if not 100%) that if you have Android 2.3 on there then its rooted.

Comment: Some one installed it for me.  Not sure how they went about it.  So now that it is rooted can i install VillainROM 3.4 instead?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably rooted.  If not, then it was in order to install 2.3, and it can be rooted again.  If you have the SuperUser app, that should be a clear indication that it's rooted.

You should definitely be able to downgrade.

The best source for ROMs is generally the Android Development subforum for a particular device on XDA.  In this case, [this subforum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=512).

Comment: Thank you i have installed VillainROM 3.4 .. Thanks for all the help